# Error when implementing havingRaw() with max()

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I'm trying to translate this SQL query to knex:

```
select
    "events".*,
    "events"."id",
    "events"."version",
    "events"."reviewed_at",
    "events"."source_id"
from "events"
inner join "events" as "events2" on "events".source_id = "events2".source_id
inner join "event_dates" on "events"."id" = "event_dates"."event_id"
where "event_dates"."end_date" > 'NOW()' 
group by
    "events"."id",
    "events"."version",
    "events"."reviewed_at",
    "events"."source_id"
having MAX("events2".reviewed_at) = "events".reviewed_at;
```

But I can't seem to get the `havingRaw()` part right. Here's my `havingRaw()` as of now:

```
.havingRaw('MAX("events2".reviewed_at) = ?', "events".reviewed_at)
```

My query gets executed if I exclude `havingRaw(..)` but I really need to add the having condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least your code seems to have syntax error and you are using `raw` API wrong:

```
.havingRaw('MAX("events2".reviewed_at) = ?', "events".reviewed_at)
```

You are trying to read attribute `reviewed_at` of string literal `"event"`... try:

```
.havingRaw('MAX(??) = ??', ["events2.reviewed_at", "events.reviewed_at"])
```

Where `??` is identifier substitution, where it gets automatically correctly quoted. If you use just `?` replacement, `knex` tries to pass substitution as a value binding to database driver.